# Charting widget for GTK or Qt

Tags: qt, gtk, charts, stocks

Is there a widget for GTK or Qt that would allow me to draw stock charts like this?

http://smartquant.com/openquant/openquant_chart.jpg
(copy&paste the URL due to hotlinking restriction)

Thanks, Joel

Comment: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/do_you_provide_a_tool_for_creating_graphs

Comment: for those still interested in this, see if qcustomplot is packaged for your operating system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qwt can handle it and Uwe Rathmann the main developer is active and helpfull

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

mail thread on financial charting.
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=78f82c3e0903191242m52567cb8ja2de6a273ed4b8be%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=qwt-interest

Answer (score 5):

How about [GTKGraph](http://gtkgraph.sourceforge.net/)?  Or see if you can pull something out of [Grism](http://www.grism.org/)?  The [author writes](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/132689):

> I draw stock charts using a
>   GtkDrawingArea and a Cairo context. 
>   The charts are not animated, but if
>   you resize the chart window, the chart
>   automatically resizes (actually, it
>   performs a redraw).

Answer (score 1):

There's [KD Chart](http://www.ics.com/products/qt/kdchart/) for Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [NightCharts](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=132560).

But you should keep in mind, that it's a self-made thing without any support and seemingly its development has been stopped already. So probably there may be a plenty of bugs.

And one more thing. IMHO it draws the most pretty pie charts among other Qt chart libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Medsphere has made their graphing widget available, note that it's implemented in gtk# though.

http://medsphere.org/projects/widgets/wiki/Graph