# Stock Charts in C++

Tags: c++, charts

I am trying to create some charts of data (eg http://www.amibroker.com/).  Is there a C++ library that can do this without a lot of extra work?  I'm thinking Qt or wxWindows would have something like it, but it wasn't immediately obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731417/charting-widget-for-gtk-or-qt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net) does at least some of the things you are trying to achieve (basic plots, bar charts and so on), and integrates well with Qt.

Answer (score 4):

[FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) is a light and portable C++ toolkit for GUI. There's a [chart class](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Chart.html). [Sample](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/charts.gif).

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to pick your GUI framework first, then find a charting control for the given framework, since that affects what charting controls you could feasibly use.  For example, must this be portable?

For the project I'm working on (a large MFC application) we use Cedric Moonen's [ChartCtrl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/High-speedCharting.aspx).  We've had a pretty good experience with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some graph plotting with gnuplot lately, which is quite powerful. Although I think it is Linux only, which may or may not be a problem.

Also, believe it or not, some amazing things can be done with LaTeX. I've used the tkz (tikz) library to produce some awesome graphs.

Both solutions plot to a file which you can include in your interface.

They aren't C++ libraries but you can easily create the datafiles and call the necessary programs from within your C++ program (Being creative with system() and possible some shell scripts).

Comment: gnuplot is available for Windows.