# What is the best way to draw charts in c++

Tags: c++, charts

What is the best way to draw charts in c++ ?? So far I've been using external program (gnuplot) to draw charts. I generated a configuration file and file with data to draw. However I think it's not the best solution. What is in Your opinion the best library to draw charts in c++??

Comment: Draw charts how?  To a printer?  To a file?  To the screen?

Comment: Sounds like a good approach to me.

Comment: Why do you think it's not the best solution? You've separated your data generation from your chart drawing - that sounds awesome.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ (kidding) (mostly).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Free easy way to draw graphs and charts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765408/c-free-easy-way-to-draw-graphs-and-charts)

Comment: Duplicate question. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128061/stock-charts-in-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765408/c-free-easy-way-to-draw-graphs-and-charts

Comment: Kind of depends on what you want those charts for. You can improve your solution by not generating the temporary file and simply writing the data into gnuplots input.

Answer (score -3):

A `chart` is not really a well defined output format. In a way the bunch of numbers sent to gnuplot are already a kind of chart.

To answer to your question you should define what you mean by chart : some image with a given format ? some html source code ? etc.

Comment: ^ This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Seth Johnson: I disagree with that point of view. In it's current form the correct answer is 'there is no possible answer' and the reason there is no answer (and can't be any) is because as I said a chart is not a well defined output format. ie: the word `chart` can only be understood by a human being and has no meaning for a computer. Others indeed gave similar answers in comments, but they just answered in comments.